# Not getting All data from list while using DBFlow database

Tags: android

```
I add Some data of list in DbFlow Databse but when I want that data get only one from list .
Here is my code for reference 

for(i in path.indices){
   val image_off_obj=UserObject()
   image_off_obj.image_path=path[i].toString()
   image_off_obj.save()
}
```

**Below syntax is for getting data from database, but I got only one from it.**
    //Output
     val image_data = SQLite
                    .select()
                    .from(UserObject::class.java)
                    .queryList()

Answer (score 0):

Add one Id in your database with autoincrement= true.
Like this :->

```
@Column
 @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true)
 var image_id :Int =0
```